# Defining spring bean using a class with generic parameters

Tags: java, generics, spring

If I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Enum<T>> {
  public void setFoo(T[] foos) {
    ....
  }
}
```

How would I go about declaring this as a bean in my context xml so that I can set the Foo array assuming I know what T is going to be (in my example, let's say T is an enum with the values ONE and TWO)?

At the moment, having something like this is not enough to tell spring what the type T is:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="example.MyClass">
  <property name="foo">
    <list>
      <value>ONE</value>
      <value>TWO</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Edit: Forgot the list tag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spring has no generic support for that case, but the compiler just creates a class cast in this case. So the right solution is:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="example.MyClass">
  <property name="foo">
    <list value-type="example.MyEnumType">
      <value>ONE</value>
      <value>TWO</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: A comment a long time in coming.  I'm probably missing something since no-one else has spoken up on this.  This can't be a general solution, right?  In the provided sample, we're just stuffing `T`'s into an `Array[]` basically, which will work.  But what if `T` is a base class for a number of concrete types with overloaded methods.  What is the actual type of the bean returned by Spring?  It can't be any of the concrete types, as the code knows nothing of them, so it would basically have no implementation behind it.  The more general subject of this question is the reason I bering this up.

Comment: ...oh...I think I was right in knowing I was missing something.  I see it now maybe.  It's the fact that we've specified a concrete type for `T` by way of the type of the list (`example.MyEnumType`) that we're passing into the getter on the main class.  I hope that works, 'cause I have a real need for it to.  Seems pretty hacky though.  It's been 13 years.  Can Spring do better with this case now?

Answer (score 16):

Consider working example.

```
<bean id="simpleInt" 
      class="org.nipr.gateway.service.transaction_assistant.GenericSimple">
    <constructor-arg>
        <!-- this can be any full path to a class -->
        <value>java.lang.Integer</value> 
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="simpleString"  
      class="org.nipr.gateway.service.transaction_assistant.GenericSimple">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>java.lang.String</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Simple generic class:

```
public class GenericSimple<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    public GenericSimple(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public T get( T t) {
        return t;
    }
}
```

And finally, the test method (using factory):

```
public void testGeneric(){
    Factory factory = new Factory(new String[]{"config/beanForGenericTest.xml"});

    GenericSimple<Integer> simpleInt 
        = (GenericSimple<Integer>)factory.getClass("simpleInt");
    System.out.println(simpleInt.get(Integer.valueOf(100)));
    Assert.assertTrue(simpleInt.get(Integer.valueOf(100)).equals(100));

    GenericSimple<String> simpleString = 
        (GenericSimple<String>)factory.getClass("simpleString");
    System.out.println(simpleString.get(new String("Rockets go fast.")));
    Assert.assertTrue(simpleString.get("Rockets go fast.")
        .equals("Rockets go fast."));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="myClass" class="example.MyClass">
  <property name="foo">
    <list>
      <value>ONE</value>
      <value>TWO</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Alternatively, you can define a [custom editor](http://www.stehno.com/node/21).

Comment: How does spring know which enum ONE and TWO came from?